# Beaglebone Black: GPIO pin export and unexport

Tags: c++, beagleboard

I am diving into Linux on BBB, following [this page](http://www.armhf.com/using-beaglebone-black-gpios/).  Can someone explain to me what export and unexport do, and why they are needed?  Can't you just write straight into the virtual file system with out those two steps?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, how is this an Ubuntu question?

Comment: My dev machine runs on Ubuntu, and the BBB runs on Debian which is also Linux.

Comment: See https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black and http://derekmolloy.ie/gpios-on-the-beaglebone-black-using-device-tree-overlays/ .